# P(A or B | C) =? P(A|C)+P(B|C)

Tags: bayes-theorem

I would like to calculate the probability of either $A$ or $B$ or both given $C$.
If A and B are mutually exclusive ($P(A,B)=0$) then I believe it is true that 
$P(A or B | C) = P(A|C)+P(B|C)$  although I have not seen this 'officially stated' in a brief search.

Is this true when A and B can occur simultaneously?  When they are dependent?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 3):

$P(A \text{ or }B \mid C) = P(A\mid C)+P(B\mid C)$ is true if and only if $P(A \text{ and }B \mid C) = 0$

In other words, conditioning on event $C$ happening, you want $A$ and $B$ to be mutually exclusive, or at least have zero probability of occuring

More generally,  $P(A \text{ or }B \mid C) = P(A\mid C)+P(B\mid C) - P(A \text{ and }B \mid C)$ as an example of [inclusion-exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle)

Comment: ok tk this looks good

Answer (score 1):

A proof of the Henry's formula
$$
P(\text{$A$ or $B$}\mid C) = P(A\cup B\mid C) = \frac{P((A\cup B)\cap C)}{P(C)} = \frac{P((A\cap C)\cup(B\cap C))}{P(C)}
$$
$$
= \frac{P(A\cap C)+P(B\cap C)- P((A\cap B) \cap C)}{P(C)} = P(A\mid C)+P(B\mid C) - P(A\cap B\mid C)
$$